# Multi type, Multi Dimentional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, types

Looking for ways to achieve  in Java to define multi dimensional arrays with each index being of different type

Something like this...

below 'values' and 'activities' are related.. but lack of such structure they are declared independently.

```
final String[] values = new String[]{
        "Config",
        "Linking Twitter & Facebook",
        "Facebook Direct",
        "Twitter Direct",
        "Action Bar (Profiled)",
        "Sharing",
        "Comments",
        "Likes",
        "Views",
        "Entities",
        "User Profile (Profiled)",
        "Actions (User Activity)",
        "Subscriptions",
        "Location",
        "Init",
        "Tools"
    };

    final Class<?>[] activities = new Class<?>[]{
        AuthButtonsActivity.class,
        FacebookActivity.class,
        TwitterActivity.class,
        ActionBarActivity.class,
        ShareActivity.class,
        CommentActivity.class,
        LikeActivity.class,
        ViewActivity.class,
        EntityActivity.class,
        UserActivity.class,
        ActionActivity.class,
        SubscriptionActivity.class,
        LocationActivity.class,
        InitActivity.class,
        ToolsActivity.class
    };
```

It should have been declared something like this.. if java had a support..

```
Array<String, Class>[][] valueClasses = 

 final Array<String, Class>[][] valueClasses = new Array<String, Class>[][]{
        {  "Config",  AuthButtonsActivity.class },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an implementation of the `Map` interface. Your initialization code can become something like this:

```
private static Map<String, Class<?>> assembleActivitiesMap() {
  Map<String, Class<?>> activities = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

  activities.put("Config", AuthButtonsActivity.class);
  activities.put("Facebook", FacebookActivity.class);
  ...
  return activities;

private final Map<String, Class<?>> activities = assembleActivitiesMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow what you're going for, but have a look at the collections in [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained). The `Multimap` might be what you're looking for.